# Unable to find group (Fog::Compute::AWS::NotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

Amazon ec2 with rubber deploy error. When i run create staging I got following error.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:10:in `response_call': Unable to find group 'Matchimi_Enterprise_production_default' (Fog::Compute::AWS::NotFound)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:353:in`response'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in`error_call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:260:in`rescue in request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:220:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in`error_call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:260:in`rescue in request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:220:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/idempotent.rb:12:in`error_call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:10:in `error_call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:260:in`rescue in request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/excon-0.23.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:220:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:25:in`request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:385:in `_request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:380:in`request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/aws/requests/compute/authorize_security_group_ingress.rb:54:in `authorize_security_group_ingress'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/fog-1.12.1/lib/fog/aws/models/compute/security_group.rb:104:in`authorize_port_range'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:368:in `add_security_group_rule'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:500:in`block (2 levels) in sync_security_groups'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:496:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:496:in`block in sync_security_groups'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:490:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:490:in`sync_security_groups'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:254:in `setup_security_groups'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb:72:in`before_create_instance'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/thread_safe_proxy.rb:13:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:267:in`block in create_instance'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:266:in`create_instance'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubber-2.5.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in create_instances'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.

I remove the gem with github link from my gem file. I figured out that some time if you associate gem directed from github, you will get deploy error if that github link is down. So, should avoid adding github link in your gemfile to be save in deployment.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me and the reason was I was using my user name for the account field as opposed to my AWS account number. I'm assuming that if the account number is wrong, a similar error will ensue.